# Why is there a large difference in readability between the C# and ECMAScript specifications?

Tags: c#, javascript, ecma262

I have been studying the ECMAScript specification and have found that it is extremely hard to read and understand. I constantly have to backtrack to keep concepts in my head. When reading the C# specification I am able to study components of the language without constantly moving around the document.

[ECMAScript Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf)

[C# Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)

Comment: JavaScript existed for several years as an implementation for years before the specification was written. C# was carefully specified before it was implemented.

Comment: Note that you're finding a difference in clarity or readability, not quality.

Comment: @Gabe - Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Because JavaScript sucked since the inception or maybe because you get what you pay for :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As I am the only person regularly posting on SO who has been a member of both the C# language design committee and the ECMAScript technical committee, I can probably offer a few insights.

First off, thanks for your kind words about the C# specification. We've worked very hard  to keep it readable and it is good to know that we've succeeded.

Second, I note that the C# specification was not always that way. The C# 2.0 specification was written as an *addendum* to the C# 1.0 specification. Generics, iterator blocks and anonymous methods had widespread impacts on many sections of the specification. It was a real pain reading the 2.0 spec and having to jump around between two chapters to understand the real overload resolution algorithm. Mads did a huge amount of editing work in C# 3.0 to first integrate all the C# 2.0 changes into a reasonable place in the spec so that you would not have to jump around all over the place.

Third, a big part of what you're describing is a result of differences in both goal and style of the principal architects of the two specifications. Imagine a spectrum of "technical-ness" with papers about formal correctness written largely in Greek letters at one end, and magazine articles for beginners on the other. We design the C# specification to fall at a particular place on that spectrum. We do not want it to be a beginner programmer tutorial, but do want it to be a reasonable document for beginner C# programmers to consult.  Anders specifically wished to avoid what he calls "the higher math of the specification".

This is a reasonable set of goals given our target audience for the spec: professional  programmers, some of whom want to learn C#, and some of whom want to look up precisely how something works. The spec has vague tutorial aspects and precise semantic description aspects in order to serve those two constituencies.

Waldemar Horwat, the principal author of the ECMAScript 3 spec, had rather different goals for the E3 spec -- not worse goals, but different goals. The goal of the E3 spec was to be far more towards the *mathematically precise* end of the spectrum. You'll note how practically every section of the specification consists of essentially pseudocode algorithms that describe in rather math-heavy prose precisely what the effect of each operation is on the system.

You'll notice for example that the E3 specification talks about the difference between "mathematical" numbers and their binary representations. One draft of the E4 spec even went so far as to note that there are set-theoretic problems with a naive definition of "type" as a set of values if types are also values. This sort of thing would be completely out of place in the C# spec; it does not seek to have a strong theoretical mathematical underpinning to ensure its correctness. You'll note that the C# spec nowhere even defines "type" -- it was written with the assumption that the readers will be pro devs who (1) already know what types are for practical purposes, and (2) neither know nor care what set theory or category theory has to say about the mathematical well-foundedness of any definition of "type".

The goal of the ECMAScript process was for multiple vendors of highly similar languages to come together and agree on a precise description of what was in the common ground amongst all those implementations. The E3 spec was never intended to be a tutorial of any kind, and is primarily aimed at language and tool *implementors*, rather than language *users*.

Waldemar's E4 spec went even further. If I recall correctly, he began by specifying a very precise, simple "spec language" with clear semantics. Then he wrote an interpreter for that language in Common Lisp. Then he wrote the E4 spec in his spec language. The result was that he could *compile the specification itself into a working ECMAScript interpreter*. That is exactly the sort of "higher math" that we are trying to avoid in the C# specification. This is an awesome approach to specification if you want to be incredibly precise and accurate, but it is a terrible way to write a document that *language users* can learn from.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does. Incidentally I am working on an implementation of ECMAScript which might explain why I would even ask such a question. I am beginning to see the power of the notation but I never thought that this would be a place that would slow down my work (Read: fun).

Comment: "The result was that he could compile the specification itself into a working ECMAScript interpreter." O_O That is insane but cool. And +1 for an one of the most informative answers I've found on SO.

Comment: I don't see why he went that far. The C# spec is extremely clear, and easy to implement. It has very few "bugs", e.g. places where it may be understood to mean something different than it actually does.

Comment: @configurator: Thanks! However if you try to do a word-for-word strict implementation of the spec, you quickly start to find places where things are vague or even impossible. We try to fix those up when we find them but the list of spec bugs is pretty long and we don't always get to all of them.

Comment: @Eric: I'm sure the ECMAScript spec has bugs as well... Everything that is complicated enough would have bugs in it (unless _I_ wrote it of course :P)

Comment: @Eric: If you get stuck implementing the spec word-for-word, then you guys aren't using the spec to implement, but as a after-the-fact documentation? I actually don't know the purpose of the spec so it might just be to get more info but not all the details about something. Also if C# spec and the actual C# doesn't match 100%, then I assume there is potentially knowledge that could be lost? (Without trying to work it out by reading code). Anyway was just curious when you said that.

Comment: @Joan: We try to write the spec first and then write the implementation to the spec. What ends up happening in practice is that as we attempt to write the implementation, we discover that the spec is impossible or wrong. It's an ongoing process.

Comment: Thanks Eric, you are right. Didn't think it was an ongoing process where one affects the other.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably experiencing a difference between the readability of the specifications of the two languages because they were written by different groups of people, and discuss languages which employ different object paradigms.

The JavaScript specification was written by a committee after the language had evolved organically after several years. The C# specification was written by a small group of corporate engineers while the language was growing in a controlled manner.

C# is class-centric OOP and JavaScript is prototype-centric. It is possible that if you are not as familiar with one as you are with the other, then some material may be difficult to understand at first, especially when it gets into implementation details. That doesn't necessarily indicate a problem with the clarity and readability of a specification.

Answer (score 1):

Relative to conventional languages JavaScript is very strange. In fact there aren't too many popular languages that like JavaScript are prototype based. JavaScript is completely object based, and all objects are essentially associative arrays with functions too being first-class object. This isn't typically what you'd expect to see from a language however with popularity of Ajax and browser side programming JavaScript has become the language of the web. While these strange specs could have been avoided, I believe JavaScript can lead to some interesting and creative coding. Closures for example are the thing that most new developers struggle to understand but in my experience they are very useful. The semantic of the language at times fools developers to think JavaScript is a flavor of C but soon they realize this to be not true.

To me C# is the pinnacle of programming languages. It is correct and inline with academic expectations. Its a shame that MS is the primary driver of this language. Like myself I'm sure there are many others who would enjoy a proper implementation of a platform with support for C# on none Windows based system (Mono is a move in the right direction).

If you are keen to learn JavaScript and not a JavaScript Framework, then I really suggest to stick with books that directly discuss JavaScript. However if you are intending to get started and don't care much about the ins and outs of JavaScript @bwawok suggestion of books is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are the first person I know of trying to learn a language based on the ECMA documents. Anyhow, I would say the difference is mostly due to the skill of the people writing the specs. C# is obviously a little easier to specify (due to the less dynamic nature - as already pointed out), but at the end...
...IIRC JavaScript is design by committee (many people writing also on the spec), while C# was done by Microsoft by ONE person at the end, maybe with 1-2 authors along the way and some helpers, but at the end it is Anders Hejlsberg (hope I spelled that right). Design by committee and having to vote on things may sometimes lead to less optimal "design" of a document.

So, at the end I think it is about the skill of the people writing the different specifications that one is harder to read than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the reason is that the standard you link to is actually ECMAScript. JavaScript, JScript and ActionScript are all implementations of ECMAScript, and ECMAScript was written to encompass the common parts of each. In contrast, C# was designed primarily by three people (according to the ECMA-334 standard) at Microsoft.

Other than that, you'd have to take it up with the [committee](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/PressReleases/PR_Ecma%20Technical%20Committee%2039%20coalesces%20on%20future%20direction%20of%20Web%20Programming%20Language.htm) that wrote the ECMAScript Standards.

Comment: I originally had ECMAScript as the title but its been known to cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, it's probably because they were written by different authors. The C# spec was written by Microsoft who had a vested interest in making it good (so that it would be accepted) whereas the ECMAScript spec was written by a committee after the language was already in use.

Comment: That's what I was thinking at first, but ECMA-334 credits tech. committee 39 (TC39), task group 2 (TG2) with writing the C# ECMA standard (which is what ChaosPandion links to), though they may have been working from MS documentation, or been staffed primarily with people who worked on the original design.

Answer (score -4):

Well the best part is, C# will run from one computer to another the same (yes maybe minor differences in .net versions, but stuff will generally behave). Javascript will run very different between internet explorer vs firefox vs chrome.

For example you have a webpage with an element

```
<input type="text" name="fred" />
```

And you run the JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("fred")
```

Internet explorer will get you the element (even though this is wrong behavior, there is no element with an ID of fred), but firefox will give you a null.

More likely than not, this is because of how the languages grew. C# was made by 1 company and developers were forced to follow the standards, or their code would not work. JavaScript was implemented in many different browsers in different ways, and people were free to add or remove or change functions as they saw fit.

In summary, JavaScript takes more work to learn than other languages because of it's history. Look into a good library like JQuery to abstract away the browser differences, and you should get the hang of it quick enough. Learning from a document is only a small part of learning a language... do some coding and learn how it works, and it will make sense.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ECMAScript the *language*.  You'll note that specification does not even mention `getElementById`, which is part of the W3C DOM (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html).